# jQuery Show/Hide element based on Condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

Alright. I've below Code. What I want to perform is that, Upon Clicking a Link, Show/Hide (toggle) very NEXT `div` having classname `subsec` & Hide all other divs with classname `subsec`. Also, On Clicking anywhere OUTSIDE the link & Opened div (`div.subsec`), Hide the latter (`div.subsec`).

```js
$(".links").on("click", function(){

 $(this).next("div.subsec").toggle("slow");

});
```

```css
.subsec{
  display: none;
}

.mainDivs{
  float: left;
 padding: 25px;
}

li{
 border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDivs">

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="links">Link 1</a>

<div class="subsec">
<ul>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>

<div class="mainDivs">

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="links">Link 2</a>

<div class="subsec">
<ul>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jenson555/5ruvx1mv/)**

Toggle method works well but need to close previously opened div as well upon clicking any other links or anywhere in the document outside link/opened div (`div.subsec`).

What is the best way to achieve?? Thanks in advance. Cheers!!

Comment: Wherever possible, try to make a working snippet.  This is handy as external links might become stale, and having a working snippet gives you a better chance of somebody helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the document onclick to listen to all clicks.

I check if what I click and find out if I want to keep were I've clicked, and hide everything else.

I've put comments in each check, so for example if you want it so that when you also click inside a .subsec you can comment that part out.. etc..

```js
$(".links").on("click", function(){
 $(this).next("div.subsec").toggle("slow");
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  var $e = $(e.target);
  var keep;
  //if the link is clicked, keep the next .subsec
  if ($e.is('a')) keep = $e.next();
  //if we click inside a .subsec, also keep
  if ($e.is('.subsec')) keep = $e;
  //if our parent is a .subsec keep too
  var $c = $e.closest('.subsec');
  if ($c.length) keep = $c;  
  //now we know what we want to keep, lets hide others
  $('.subsec').not(keep).hide('slow')       
});
```

```css
.subsec{
  display: none;
}

.mainDivs{
  float: left;
 padding: 25px;
}

li{
 border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDivs">

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="links">Link 1</a>

<div class="subsec">
<ul>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>

<div class="mainDivs">

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="links">Link 2</a>

<div class="subsec">
<ul>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is what I wanted!! Thanks Mate..Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to target all other subsec element and hide them. You can do that by targeting all element with class subsec and filter out target subsec using `:not` selector:

```
var subsec = $("div.subsec");
$(".links").on("click", function(){
   var target = $(this).next("div.subsec");
   subsec.not(target).hide('slow')
   target.toggle("slow");
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/udun60fq/)**

Comment: Beat me to it! Dang!

Comment: @Milind But it doesn't hide Opened div if I click outside.

Comment: @JensonMJohn you can listen to your <body> or document to handle that scenario, just be sure to stopPropagation on the click event of '.links'

Answer (score 1):

Hi try with following code.

```
var _clicked = false;
$(".links").on("click", function(){
 $(".subsec").hide("slow");
 $(this).next("div.subsec").toggle("slow");
$(window).off("click",onWindowClick);
$(window).on("click",onWindowClick);
_clicked = true;

});
function onWindowClick(e)
{
if(!_clicked && !(e.target.parentNode && e.target.parentNode.parentNode && e.target.parentNode.parentNode.className =='subsec' ))
   {
     $(".subsec").hide("slow");
     $(window).off("click",onWindowClick);
   }
   _clicked = false;

}
```

Comment: Haven't you noticed that it hides even clicks on the opened `div`??